# API call to send Event Measurment to GoogleAnalytics4 not working, why?

Tags: api, google-analytics-api

My goal is to send event measurements to Google Analytics 4 via an API call that I have created in MAKE.com.

Despite following the instructions in the docs, the event doesn't appear on Google Analytics when I test it out, here's what I did:

```
Url: https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect
Header:
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: f"Bearer xxxxxxxxxx
   measurement_id: G-4QZS3X60QX

Body Type: raw `these are dropdowns on MAKE.com`
Content type: JSON `these are dropdowns on MAKE.com`
Request content: `this is a heading on MAKE.com`
{
"client_id": "{{uuid}}",
"events": [
    {
        "name": "Appointment_Booked",
        "params": {
            "event_category": "Lead",
            "event_action": "Booked_an_appointment"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here, I can't seem to figure it out and I am going crazy after testing this numerous time